# how to access an array element from tempdata

Tags: arrays, asp.net-mvc

My question is fairly simple in nature, but I've found no answers anywhere on StackExchange or Google thus far.

Here is the situation:

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 project where I need to pass an array of boolean values to a view. The array size is set to the length of items on a customer record. For example:

```
var count = Customer.Items.Count;
    int index = 0;
    bool[] allowRenew = new bool[count];
```

I then update the array after passing through a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach (var item in Customer.Items)
{
  if(conditionA)
  {
     allowRenew[index] = false;
  }
  else
  {
     allowRenew[index] = true;
  }
  index += index;
}
```

Finally, I'm assigning the array to TempData so I can access it from my view, as such:

```
TempData["allowRenew"] = allowRenew;
```

So here is the issue, How can I access the array elements from my view? I was planning on using a foreach loop to generate markup and access the array elements based off an index that increments.

Generally, you'd access array elements like this:

```
array[1]
```

or

```
array[2]
```

But since I'm using TempData I don't know how to reference the array element. Example:

```
TempData["allowRenew"][0]
```

or

```
TempData["allowRenew"][1]
```

obviously don't work.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy; just create a variable for it in your view:

```
bool[] allowRenew = (bool[])TempData["allowRenew"];
```