# Loop foreach over List of objects (cannot operate on variables of type 'object')

Tags: c#, list, object, foreach, tempdata

I am trying to save some objects into a list for later use. Here is how I store them:

```
List<Engagement> engagementsList = new List<Engagement>();

foreach (Engagement engagement in db.Engagements)
{
    // Implementation here
}

TempData["DeletedE"] = engagementsList;
TempData.Keep();
```

Then, I am trying iterate over the list, but I get the error:

*cannot operate on variables of type 'object'*

I am iterating over the list by:

```
foreach (Engagement e in TempData["DeletedE"])
{
    // Implementation here...
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MVC's `TempData[]` indexer returns an `object`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.item(v=vs.118).aspx#P:System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Item(System.String)), over which you cannot iterate.

You need to cast it to the same type that you store in it:

```
foreach (var engagement in (List<Engagement>)TempData["DeletedE"])
{
}
```

This is also explained in [how to access an array element from tempdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23277102/how-to-access-an-array-element-from-tempdata?lq=1).

Comment: Although this should work, I am getting an error within the for loop: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' - I don't suppose you know why this might happen?

Comment: No offense, but try searching. That means something is `null`, and I suspect `TempData["DeletedE"]` to be it. Remember `TempData` only retains its values during one redirect or one controller-view transaction.

Comment: None taken, I have been debugging it and couldn't figure it out so thought there may have been something I had overlooked and yes the Temp Data has been getting passed as null.

Comment: In case you were interested, I decided to use a Session instead and all is working now :)

Answer (score 2):

Since `TempData["DeletedE"]` is of type `object`, then you cannot enumerate it.

To do that, you have to cast it to `IEnumerable<Engagement>` like this:

```
var enumerable = TempData["DeletedE"] as IEnumerable<Engagement>;

foreach (Engagement e in enumerable)
{

}
```

Comment: How would I 'add' elements to this IEnumerable?

Comment: If you need to add items, then cast to `IList<Engagement>` or `List<Engagement>` instead of `IEnumerable<Engagement>`

Comment: You don't want to modify model properties in a view.

Answer (score 0):

change your loop to this:

```
foreach (Engagement e in TempData["DeletedE"].Cast<Engagement>())
{   
}
```

Comment: There is no `Cast<T>()` extension method that works on `object`.

Comment: Oh, I see, it was not clear of what type TempData is, so you'll have to cast it first. There are some correct answers now